# What is the exact difference between <div> and <section>? Like I know Section has 'meaning' and div doesn't, but what does that mean?

Tags: html, css

I mean, based on my research, I know that  acts the same way as , except that section has meaning and div doesn't. What does that mean exactly?
Will using section output it differently on the browser than when you use div?
I'm just trying to visualize the difference.. Please don't give me any googled answers cause I've googled it and still not understanding it 100%.
Is it just solely for readability? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation of section on the W3 wiki:

> The `<section>` element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application.
>
> - A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content:
>
>   - chapter
>   - various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box
>   - numbered sections of a thesis ...
> - A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an
>     introduction, news items, and contact information.
> - The section element
>     is not a generic container element. The section element is appropriate
>     only if the contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>     outline. [[Example A]](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section#Example_A)
> - A section typically with a heading.

The `<div>` tag is to be used as a [general flow container](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html). The spec has defined permitted contents:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#flow-content

Answer (score 0):

They will not have any difference in terms out output, the point of using sections over divs is to increase semantic value in your code, or in otherwords, to make it more readable later on when you, or others, are going back and trying to understand what it does.

Comment: A little more to the point, div has no semantic value but a section does